# can we set browser args on katalon studio?

Tags: html, webrtc, functional-testing, katalon-studio

I need to mock the permission access for camera/mic while running my test related to webrtc.

Usually done by `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`, [reference](https://webrtc.org/testing/).

How do we set this browser argument in katalon studio?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Chrome Options? You can set custom browser (this is for Chrome, but there are options for other browsers as well) options like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DriverFactory.getChromeDriverPath())
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

Note: you will need to import these:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
```